# Error: SQL Substring with the "ON" Part of the JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, substring

I am using PostgreSQL and must join tables using substring. As I demonstrated below, xyz.MODEL and first three characters of "columnname" from abc Table should match. However, the query below does not work.

```
SELECT ..., ..., ..., ...
FROM ... AS abc
INNER JOIN ... AS xyz ON abc.SUBSTRING("columnname",1,3) = klm.MODEL
```

It returns the error:

```
ERROR:  schema "abc" does not exist
```

Can anyone help me to correct this query?

Thanks for your help already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table alias must precede the column name, not the function:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ... AS abc
  JOIN ... AS xyz ON SUBSTRING(abc."columnname",1,3) = klm.MODEL
                               ^
                               here
```